# Font awesome Rails won't work after deploying. It looks like bad Unicode characters. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, font-awesome

In my local machine fontawesome is working perfectly (Im using 4.1 gem). But when uploaded to Heroku it stops working. I looks like bad unicode characters. I have included the following line in config and precompiled assets but it didn't work :

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join(‘app’, ‘assets’, ‘fonts’)
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

Please look at this image :

[image]

On the left is the problem. On the right is the correct version. What might be the problem? Here's the link to the Heroku app : http://fast-garden-6871.herokuapp.com/

**Update** It looks like `/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot` is missing in the production machine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it! In custom.css I added the following lines:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

The problem was, rails will generate the font file with a hash like it generate css files. But the css is not updated with this new generated file. So the system can't find the font. With the above code, the system will assign the right url!

Answer (score 2):

In your css file, change url to asset-url under @font-face.

Also did you precompile assets after deployment?

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Yes I did it but no luck