# Font Awesome 5 Some bad Unicode characters

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I am seeing some strange behavior with the new fontAwesome 5; Some icons seem to show up just fine, and others appear as if they were bad unicode characters:

[image: Bad FontAwesome 5 characters]

It appears to be a similar issue to [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044660/font-awesome-rails-wont-work-after-deploying-it-looks-like-bad-unicode-charact), except that I am not using Ruby on Rails. Another difference here is that I tried adding a full path (rather than the relative path used) to the fonts in `fontawesome-all.css`, with no change.

Code:

```
<i class="far fa-chart-pie fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> <!-- doesn't show -->
<i class="far fa-id-card fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> <!-- shows -->
```

Reference to the css in `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/res/plugins/Font-Awesome/5.0.2/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.css">
```

Comment: I recommend using the fontawesome-all.min.css to save data which has to be downloaded. It is the same code but without line breaks or spaces.

Comment: I was using it, but was using the non-min when trying the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't have a pro license.

To use the regular theme for the chart-pie you need the pro license, for the regular version of the id card you don't.

```
<i class="far fa-id-card"></i>
<i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>
```

Just look on the official font awesome site at https://fontawesome.com/icons and then see if you can choose regular from the menu on the right. Some icons don't have this option for free. There you need to use the "fas" css class and not the "far" class.

Comment: This seems to be the case. FontAwesome seems to have a misleading search function, where it is not obvious what style the icons in the results are. I thought the `chart-pie` was a free regular as it showed up in a 'free' search, and there was nothing to say it was of any particular style.

Comment: apparently you have to look closely to the color of the icons. If you hover you also see the "pro" flag. But yes, it could be better made. Also that some icons are available regular and some are only with the pro license